# PyGame Negative Color / Surface

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm creating a game with PyGame. There I want to create negative effect, where all screen becomes negative.

This is quite easy for simple shapes like rects: (and use `rect` instead of `pygame.draw.rect`)

```
# set negative to 1 to activate effect
negative = 0

def rect(win, color, area, width=0):
    if negative:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255 - color[0], 255 - color[1], 255 - color[2]), area, width)
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, color, area, width)
```

But I don't know how to do this effect on images. I tried to do negative image copy, but if this effect will not be instant and will fill screen gradually, then this will not help.

```
# negative image copy
def negcopy(image):
    neg = pygame.Surface(image.get_size())

    for y in range(image.get_height()):
        for x in range(image.get_width()):
            c = image.get_at((x, y)
            neg.set_at((x, y), (255 - color[0], 255 - color[1], 255 - color[2], 255))

    return neg
```

Comment: You may want to look at pixarray, an interface to the under-the-hood buffer which stores the pixel, to have faster read/write ops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) with the *special_flag* argument `BLEND_SUB` for this.
Create a completely white image with the same size and *subtract* the original image:

```py
neg = pygame.Surface(image.get_size())
neg.fill((255, 255, 255))
neg.blit(image, (0, 0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_SUB)
```